# Finding the outer ends of lines in a line feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, line, extents

I have a polyline feature class and need to turn the ends of the lines into points. However, the lines are made up of segments that are not quite contiguous, with slight gaps between many of the segments. In effect, the lines are dashed, with varying lengths of the gaps and segments. Is there any way, in ArcGIS, to find only the points that are at the ends of the dashed lines, not at the starts and ends of the "dashes"?

Comment: If you know the gap distance for the dashed lines, you could search on buffer of 2/3 the distance from a point at 1/2 the distance along the line path. It's pretty basic trigonometry from there (and doesn't require more than a Basic license).  You'd still need to review corners/turns to connect the dots in at least a small sample or th cases.

Comment: The length of the gaps in the dashed lines varies, I think. As does the length of the line segments.

Comment: Give it a try anyway. GIS SE is more a place for problem-solving than brain-storming, so bringing a tangible issue is going to get better results than bringing one which is light on details.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a few images of your data to help us understand what _exactly_ you have.

Comment: Are there common attributes for the lines, or are they only identifiable by visually identifying the gaps?

Comment: The lines have no common attributes, or else this would have been much easier. On that occasion, I ended up doing this in a time-consuming, manual way, having only the Basic license for ArcGIS Desktop and no Network Analyst extension, either. For future reference, I need to figure out if this (finding the "true ends" of lines) and, more importantly, the tracing of upstream paths along a network can be done with the Python networkx module and the results exported to a shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

You can significantly reduce number of potential candidates by applying spatial join of end points to line segments:

[image]

Join them to segments:

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis("ends", "segments", "in_memory/sj", "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY",.. , "INTERSECT", **"70 Meters"**)
```

and find frequency of highlighted field:

[image]

Transfer frequency to original table of end points. After 3 iterations with distance in spatial join (gap length?), I was able to achieve this (note count of point in legend):

[image]

All of it doable with Basic license. Tip: use results window to make iterations more efficient.

Comment: I have tried this approach, and the result was less than satisfactory; points were produced at the ends of lines, but also elsewhere. I cannot think of a better solution than to simplify the lines by converting them to a raster (coarse enough for adjacent segments to be blurred together), then back to polyline and only then to use the method with the spatial joins you described.

Comment: If you managed to connect lines you can forget about this method. It's enough to find endpoints, select ones that overlap, select again by itself and delete selected. They called dangles, real easy with Advanced license...

Comment: I know. But the license I have is not Advanced, but only Basic.